# Microsoft supporting ORTC or WebRTC?

Tags: internet-explorer, opera, webrtc, screensharing, ortc

After reading multiple articles, I am left confused whether Microsoft will follow WebRTC standard or
will follow its cu-rtc successor O-RTC ?

Also Opera states its support for WebRTC for versions 18+, 
but i do not see support for `getUsermedia->chooseMediaDesktop` for screen sharing.

Similarly, does the Microsoft's ORTC standard support screen sharing? Or we wait until it supports WebRTC?

I tried CU-RTC prototype and ORTC prototypes on IE, and both are regarding to peer to peer communication.

I need to create Opera/IE plugins to allow screen sharing on web page. No other way seems to be there other than the WebRTC standard **getUserMedia -> chooseDesktopMedia**
But the same is not supported in Opera, IE and Safari(Mac)

Comment: This does not really seem like a programming question for Stackoverflow but I do believe that MS is only going to support ORTC and that currently Google is working with them to make it work in Chrome as well along side WebRTC.

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin.. I am creating add-ons for various browsers for screen sharing functionality and was stuck at Opera/IE/Safari. The plugin was successfully created in chrome and firefox. My code gives error for chooseDesktopMedia and desktopCapture permission not found for Opera and thus the doubt based on research done for the same. Well i guess we need to wait while ortc supports screen share in that case.. and keep exploring for more solutions

Comment: Ah...I understand. I am not sure if Opera has changed its desktop capture API to match the changes that Google has made(it having to be in a plugin). I have not really messed around with Opera much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Sept 18 Microsoft Edge (Spartan) is now supporting ORTC.  Links and such are below.

BLOGS
-   http://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/09/18/ortc-api-is-now-available-in-microsoft-edge/

- https://blogs.office.com/2015/09/18/enabling-seamless-communication-experiences-for-the-web-with-skype-skype-for-business-and-microsoft-edge/
- http://blogs.skype.com/2015/09/18/skype-for-web-and-skype-for-outlook-com-update/

DEMOS on Edge Test Drive
-   http://dev.modern.ie/testdrive/demos/ortcdemo/ for Edge-to-Edge video calls

- http://dev.modern.ie/testdrive/demos/twilioortc/ for Edge-to-Phone calls by Twilio
- http://dev.modern.ie/testdrive/demos/simplewebrtc for Edge-to-Chrome/FF audio calls by &yet

Open Source projects for WebRTC-ORTC interop 
-   https://webrtchacks.com/first-steps-ortc/ - blog post and open source project by &yet

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ortc-adapter - open source project launched by Twilio

Hope this helps.  Healy in Tampa

Answer (score 0):

according to this article Microsoft will be supporting both ORTC and WebRTC through getusermedia in Win10 and the Spartan browser.  This is probably a long time coming so if your planning on building an app that needs to run on IE you'll need a plugin.

ORTC as of the last I looked it over isn't very well documented in comparison to WebRTC and is still in pretty experimental stages. SIPML5 has an IE plugin already created but if the standards change you'll have to wait for them to update the plugin to correct possible bugs.  If possible use Firefox or chrome even on mobile.